# How to let MathJax only apply bold to characters?

Tags: support, mathjax

Correct but too many `\mathbf`:
$$\mathbf X^*_{lm}\mathbf\cdot\mathbf E(\mathbf x)\tag1$$

One `\mathbf` but incorrect:
$$\mathbf{ X^*_{lm}\cdot E(x)}\tag2$$

Is there something like `\mathbfco` (i.e. letter only):

```
\mathbfco{X^*_{lm}\cdot E(x)}
```

which can produce result in $(1)$?

Comment: In $(1)$ I wonder why you wish to bold `\cdot`?

Comment: Indeed making the \cdot bold makes it wrong because the spacing is spoiled. Also it seems that the second one is working perfectly  already as all the letters, even those subscripted are bold (matching the request to bold ‘letters only’)

Comment: @CalvinKhor I presume the OP's main complaint is that the asterisk and brackets (non-letters) as bolded. Although I have answered the question to get round it I really don't see why the OP is bothered by this.

Comment: To be honest I had no idea that the punctuation was bold. I only noticed that the subscript was not bold and was confused; after all, the subscript is composed of letters but it seems they may? Or may not? Want them bold

Answer (score 5):

To have a single command like `\mathbfco` means that it is able to detect the nature of each character and bold only uppercase and lowercase letters that are not subscripted or superscripted. I am almost certain that this is not possible in MathJax.

A potential alternative would be to shorten the length of code to bold, such as `\newcommand\b\mathbf` so that `\b X_{lm}^*\cdot\b E(\b x)` gives $\newcommand\b\mathbf\b X_{lm}^*\cdot\b E(\b x)$.

Comment: I also considered this, like "#define \b \mathbf" in my string mapping post.